# Monsieur versus M. initial

Tags: abréviations

Dans un cas ambigu, est-ce que l’abréviation M. est comprise comme « monsieur » ou comme une initiale de prénom ?

Par exemple M. Robespierre peut se lire Maximilien Robespierre ou Monsieur Robespierre.

Est-ce que M. Curie serait comprise comme Marie Curie ou son mari Pierre ?

Comment: Il faut la langue en contexte.  Marion Cotillard n'est pas Monsieur Cotillard.  Si elle écrit M. Cotillard sur une photo, c'est clair. Donc la question c'est pour les gens dont le prénom commence avec M dans quel contexte ?  Des prénoms inconnus des sondages, de l'arbre de famille d'antan, des voyages des émigrés du 19è siècle & c ou les noms bien connus ?

Comment: Ce sont des indices pour les certificats de naissance, des listes des recensements ou les renseignements de ceux qui ont/avaient le droit de voter ?  On voit souvent des fautes il y a pas très longtemps mais il y a en général une question de titre, état civil, sexe.  Pareille pour la carte grise et la carte bleue.

Answer (score 2):

Dans un cas ambigu, l'abréviation est… ambiguë.

Pour Robespierre, ça ne change pas grand chose, ce sera lui. J'ai de toute façon toujours lu Robespierre sans rien devant.

Pour M. Curie, il me semble qu'on comprendra toujours Marie Curie car on ne nomme pas souvent Pierre Curie "Monsieur Curie" pas plus qu'on ne dit "Madame Curie".

S'il ne s'agit pas de personnalités dont l'identité ne fait aucun doute, on peut facilement lever l'ambiguïté en mettant en toutes lettres le prénom (*Maurice Tartampion*) ou la civilité (*monsieur Tartampion*), voire en écrivant *M<sup>r</sup> Tartampion* que tout le monde comprendra<sup>1</sup>.

Le contexte peut aussi aider. S'il s'agit d'un courrier par exemple, la civilité est d'usage : *Cher M. Lenora* s'adresse à *monsieur Lenora*, pas à *Marcel Lenora*.

<sup>1</sup><sub>[Réponse de l'Académie sur le sujet, jan. 2020](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/martin-t-france):</sub>

> La septième édition du Dictionnaire de l’Académie française (1878) laissait le choix entre Mr et M. Littré, le Grand Dictionnaire de Pierre Larousse et, plus tard encore, le Larousse du xxe siècle faisaient de même. Mr a ensuite été considéré comme désuet, et la huitième édition (1935) du Dictionnaire de l’Académie ne mentionne plus que M. La neuvième édition, en cours de publication, réexaminera cette question, **car Mr connaît une nouvelle faveur : on l’utilise pour éviter la confusion avec l’abréviation des prénoms masculins commençant par M.**
>
> Mr a sur M. un autre avantage : en composition typographique et associé, comme c’est souvent le cas, à Mme, il est plus agréable à l’œil puisque le r fait pendant avec le me de Mme. C’est particulièrement vrai quand on écrit le r et le me au-dessus de la ligne, selon le meilleur usage.
>
> D’ailleurs les autres titres de civilités s’abrègent par retranchement médian et conservent leur dernière ou dernières lettres (Mme pour Madame, Mlle pour Mademoiselle, Mgr pour Monseigneur, Me pour Maître…), donc sans point abréviatif.

Comment: Rien _devant_ car c'était un _ci-devant_, si je ne me trompe :-)

Comment: @Frank Ce n'était pas un *ci-devant* mais c'est vite devenu un *ci-gît*...

Comment: "M. Aubry" désigne-t-il la maire de Lille (Martine Aubry) ou son ex-mari (monsieur Aubry) ? Même si la question titille l’Académie française, il n’est pour l’instant pas question de revenir sur cette règle (*M.* comme abbréviation de *Monsieur*, *Mr/Mr.* étant les abbréviation UK/US pour *Mister*).

Comment: @Graffito On peut espérer que le contexte permettra de s'y retrouver, ce qui est peut-être une attente réaliste.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui la Révolution fût très brutale, même envers ses enfants... Mais je croyais qu'il avait commencé comme de Robespierre. Mais bon, je ne suis pas très fort sur l'histoire de la Révolution. J'aurais du réviser pour le 14 juillet...

Comment: @Frank ***de** Robespierre* oui, mais la particule [n'implique pas nécessairement](https://anf.asso.fr/article/particule-un-signe-de-noblesse-1356) l'appartenance à l'aristocratie (ex: de Gaulle), comme l'absence de particule ne l'exclut pas (ex: Grimaldi). Les [Robespierre](https://www.geneastar.org/celebrite/robespierre/maximilien-de-robespierre) étaient une famille de bourgeois "de robe" (juges, avocats, notaires, etc.)